# How to Apply Filters to a Rally Grid View

Tags: javascript, gridview, filter, rally

I need to apply some computed filtering to the data store associated with a Rally Grid.

This code has a good bit of debugging "noise," but it shows that I'm trying to provide some filters at config time, and they're ignored, or seem to be since my filter function is not firing.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function () {
        //Write app code here
        console.log("Overall App Launch function entered");
        //API Docs: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/
    }
});

Rally.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define('BOA.AdoptedWork.MultiArtifactGrid', {
        extend: 'Rally.app.App',
        componentCls: 'app',

        launch: function () {
            console.log("onReady Launch function entered");
            this.theGrid = {
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                showPagingToolbar: true,
                showRowActionsColumn: false,
                editable: false,
                columnCfgs: [
                    'FormattedID',
                    'Name',
                    'ScheduleState',
                    'Iteration',
                    'Release',
                    'PlanEstimate',
                    'TaskEstimateTotal',
                    'TaskActualTotal', // For some reason this does not display ?? :o( ??
                    'TaskRemainingTotal'
                ],
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: {
                        fn: function (_myVar, eOpts) {
                            console.log("Arg to afterrender: ", _myVar, " and ", eOpts);
                            console.log("Filters: ", _myVar.filters);
                            var _myStore = _myVar.getStore();
                            console.log("Store : ", _myStore);
                            console.log("Store filters: ", _myStore.filters);
                        }
                    }
                },
                filters: [{
                    // This did not work ...
                    property: 'ScheduleState',
                    operator: '==',
                    value: 'Defined',
                    // Trying dynamic Filter Function.  Update: Never called.
                    filterFn: function (item) {
                        console.log("Entered Filter Function!");
                        var iter = item.get("Iteration");
                        console.log("Iteration field: ", iter);
                        if (iter !== null && iter !== undefined) {
                            return (iter.name === "Sprint 3");
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }],
                context: this.getContext(),
                storeConfig: {
                    models: ['userstory', 'defect']
                },
                scope: this
            };
            this.add(this.theGrid);
            console.log("The Grid Object: ", this.theGrid);
        }
    });


    Rally.launchApp('BOA.AdoptedWork.MultiArtifactGrid', {
        name: 'Multi-type Grid'
    });
});
```

*I have not coded in 12 years and never before in JavaScript.  So, I'm getting my bearings.*

Comment: Do not post screenshots of your code. Please copy the part needed in order to reproduce the issue so we can help you at this.

Comment: Thanks, for the coaching.  Obviously, my first post on stackoverflow.com :)

The screenshot was less congested with all the debugging noise, but perhaps you can see some things I was inspecting to try to figure things out myself. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the Rally Communities provided the answer and helpful feedback:

corkr03 said ...

@miguelfuerte a few things: 
The "filters" configuration needs to be part of the storeConfig.  In your code above it is part of the gridConfig.

```
storeConfig: {
      filters: [{
            property: "Iteration.Name",
            value: "Sprint 3"
      }]
}
```

Also, the filter for a property of "Iteration" will expect a reference to the Iteration reference.  For that particular implementation, you will want to use the property:  "Iteration.Name".   There is good information about queries and using dot notation here:  General Query Examples | CA Agile Central Help